# Reduce number of ifs in React form validation

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate if all the fields of a form are filled. So I created this validation function:

```
const validateFields = () => {
    if(values.phase_name === ''){
      return false
    }else if(values.phaseSelected === ''){
      return false
    }else if(values.first_mobilization === ''){
      return false
    }else if(values.start_before_maintenance_stop === ''){
      return false
    }else if(values.end_before_maintenance_stop === ''){
      return false
    }else if(values.start_maintenance_stop === ''){
      return false
    }else if(values. end_maintenance_stop === ''){
      return false
    }else if(values.start_startup){
      return false
    }else if(values.end_startup){
      return false
    }else if(values.demobilization === ''){
      return false
    }else{
      return true
    }
  }
```

When I click the submission button, the `validateFields` function is called. Is there a better way to validate this fields, with less if´s?

Comment: A start would be `if (Object.values(values).some(val => val === ''))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that all of the values have `length`.  This validates that every field has something in it, but you could apply negative logic too.  There are plenty of ways to do this.

```
if (Object.values(validation).every(x => x.length)) {
 // do stuff 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Either put your values in an array and loop through them as keys for your object or simply switch to an OR structure:

```
const validateFields = () => {
  if (values.phase_name === '' ||
    values.phaseSelected === '' ||
    values.first_mobilization === '' ||
    values.start_before_maintenance_stop === '' ||
    values.end_before_maintenance_stop === '' ||
    values.start_maintenance_stop === '' ||
    values.end_maintenance_stop === '' ||
    values.start_startup ||
    values.end_startup ||
    values.demobilization === '') {
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
}
```

To take it a step further, just return the boolean result of the condition:

```
return !(values.phase_name === '' ||
    values.phaseSelected === '' ||
    values.first_mobilization === '' ||
    values.start_before_maintenance_stop === '' ||
    values.end_before_maintenance_stop === '' ||
    values.start_maintenance_stop === '' ||
    values.end_maintenance_stop === '' ||
    values.start_startup ||
    values.end_startup ||
    values.demobilization === '');
```

Comment: Could be even fewer ifs with just `return !(/*all the ORs*/);` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using formik library with yup validation. These work really well together and you do not have to create such monsters. :)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik

https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup

Comment: This is not an answer, but a link to something that could be an answer. If you [edit] your answer by providing code that uses those libraries and shows how it would work in the specific example of the OP's code, then it would be good answer.

Comment: Thanks! I´ll you take a look at this lib!